# match an image to a specific frame within a video with ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, compare, match

I have some images that were taken from a video via screen capture.  I would like to know when in the video these images appear (timestamps).  Is there a way to programmatically match an image with a specific frame in a video using ffmpeg or some other tool?

I am very open to different technologies as I'm eager to automate this.  It would be extremely time consuming to do this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the psnr between that image and each frame in the video, and the match is the frame with the highest psnr. ffmpeg has a tool to calculate the psnr in tests/tiny_psnr which you can use to script this together, or there's also a psnr filter in the libavfilter module in ffmpeg if you prefer to code rather than script.

Scripting, you'd basically decode the video to a FIFO, decode the image to a file, and then match the FIFO frames repeatedly against the image file using tiny_psnr, selecting the framenumber for the frame with highest psnr. The output will be a frame-number, which (using fps output on the commandline) you can approximately convert to a timestamp.

Programming-wise, you'd decode the the video and image to AVFrame, use the psnr filter to compare the two, and then look at the output frame metadata to record the psnr value in your program, and search for the frame with the highest metadata psnr value, and for that frame, AVFrame->pkt_pts would be the timestamp.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  As I mentioned, these images were taken via screen capture.  Will the psnr value still work if the cropping is a little off?  E.g., if a few extra pixels were accidentally shaved off one side of the image?

Comment: no, psnr only works on exactly the same images (or compressed versions thereof). If they are cropped, you'll want to either shave the same number of pixels off of the reference, if you still remember how many, or do a full-pixel full-frame motion search, if you don't remember. That last option is notoriously more difficult, although the code for it does exist already (in the inner bowels of ffmpeg).

Comment: I finally had a chance to implement this.  Ffmpeg isn't giving me an overall psnr for each frame, instead if gives components (psnr_y, psnr_u, psnr_v), but it does give me a Mean Square Error (mse_avg).  I've been selecting the frame with the lowest mse_avg.  I've only done a couple of tests so far, but it's working like a champ!  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, you get it from the stats file instead of from the frame metadata, don't you? I believe you're right and psnr_avg is missing from the stats file. I'll add it so it's in the next release, sorry about that. psnr_avg is present in the frame metadata (AVDictionary *metadata = av_frame_get_metadata(f); const char *psnr_avg = av_dict_get(metadata, "lavfi.psnr.psnr_avg", NULL, 0)->value;) if you want to try that.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Do you think psnr_avg will give me different results than mse_avg?  Because of this [formula](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#psnr),  I assumed that the lowest mse_avg would correspond with the highest psnr.  But I'm a ffmpeg newb, so let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Your results will be identical, so no need to change your code, but other users may care more specifically about frame-wide psnr (as opposed to mse).